# How to specify custom CD Server URL for Language (.co.in instead of /en-in)

Tags: configuration

Im currently trying to set the publish url for a specific language on the CD server.

On the CM server the URL is `mysite.com/en-in` I want the CD servers URL to be `mysite.co.in`. How do I specify the CD server url to end with `.co.in` instead of `.com/en-in`

Running Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Add a new site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure and manage websites for different purposes and different domains by adding them to the `site` definition node in the `Sitecore.config` file. All you need to add a [patch file](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/en/using-patch-files-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html) containing the new site definition. If you have already a patch you can update it as well.

From your question it seems, everything is configured properly on CM and you just need to add separate URL for your CD website which will not contain the language in URL. For this, you need to add a new site for your CD role with a separate `hostname` and `languageEmbedding` option as `never`-

```
 <sites>
   <site name="currentSiteName" ...... />
   <!-- add new site which will inherits the current site and just override the hostName and lanagueEmbedding with role conten delivery-->
   <site name="newSiteName" inherits="currentSiteName" hostName="cdhostname.co.in" languageEmbedding="never" role:require="ContentDelivery"/>
 </sites>
```

**Update**: I noticed you are using Sitecore 8.2, so the **role-based configuration will not work** for you, you need this config as a separate config for the CD environment. one option is to manage this in the deploy pipeline.